# Will my old app works normally on Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an old app which I have to make small changes to, create a new version and update it to Google Play. Do I need to implement the new asking permissions on runtime type? Or can I just update the new version and it will work fine on Marshmallow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new Runtime Permission will work only when we set the application's targetSdkVersion to 23. And this feature will work only on Android 6.0 Marshmallow and above. The same app will run with same old behavior on pre-Marshmallow device.

If the device have Marshmallow or above, but your app's TargetSdkVersion < 23, Your app will continue to use the old permissions model, but the user can revoke permissions any time.

Any way if your app declares in its manifest that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the app that permission at install time.

Comment: If your app is using some Dangerous Permissions listed in this link https://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous will not going to work if user revoked these permissions or not granted. To prevent stopping your application you must ask user to grant permissions at run time https://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/permissions/requesting.html .

Answer (score 3):

It should still work fine if you use targetSdkVersion 22 or less. If you set targetSdkVersion 23, then your app will crash if you attempt to use a "Dangerous permission" that you did not ask the user for at runtime. Take a look at this page:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score -2):

yes, it will work on marshmallow.
just include the "target api" to '23' in your manifest file.

Comment: But, will the user be asked for permissions individually or all at once like in older SDK versions? If the user is asked for the permissions individually, and doesn't choose all of them, then the app will crash, right?

Comment: If you are using any additional permission in the new version then only the user will be asked to select it otherwise it will continue with the old permissions @belen